# Using ftransform along with fgroup_by from collapse R package

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to reproduce the following output of `dplyr` code with `R` package `collapse`.

**`dplyr` Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>%
  select(name, mass, species) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(mass_norm = mean(mass, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**`dplyr` Code Output**

```
# A tibble: 87 x 4
# Groups:   species [38]
   name                mass species mass_norm
   <chr>              <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Luke Skywalker        77 Human        82.8
 2 C-3PO                 75 Droid        69.8
 3 R2-D2                 32 Droid        69.8
 4 Darth Vader          136 Human        82.8
 5 Leia Organa           49 Human        82.8
 6 Owen Lars            120 Human        82.8
 7 Beru Whitesun lars    75 Human        82.8
 8 R5-D4                 32 Droid        69.8
 9 Biggs Darklighter     84 Human        82.8
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        77 Human        82.8
# … with 77 more rows
```

**`collapse` Code**

```
library(collapse)
starwars %>%
  fselect(name, mass, species) %>%
  fgroup_by(species) %>%
  ftransform(mass_norm = fmean(mass, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**`collapse` Code Output**

```
# A tibble: 87 x 4
   name                mass species mass_norm
 * <chr>              <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1 Luke Skywalker        77 Human        97.3
 2 C-3PO                 75 Droid        97.3
 3 R2-D2                 32 Droid        97.3
 4 Darth Vader          136 Human        97.3
 5 Leia Organa           49 Human        97.3
 6 Owen Lars            120 Human        97.3
 7 Beru Whitesun lars    75 Human        97.3
 8 R5-D4                 32 Droid        97.3
 9 Biggs Darklighter     84 Human        97.3
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        77 Human        97.3
# … with 77 more rows

Grouped by:  species  [38 | 2 (5.5)]
```

Wondering why I am getting wrong answer with `collapse` code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fmean` by default uses `na.rm = TRUE`.  Also, there is an option to specify the grouping within `fmean` i.e. `g`.  By default, `TRA` is `NULL` and it returns a summarised output, but we can change it to `replace_fill` to return the full length

```
library(collapse)
ftransform(slt(starwars, name, mass, species),
      mass_norm = fmean(mass, species, TRA = 'replace_fill'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 87 x 4
#   name                mass species mass_norm
# * <chr>              <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 Luke Skywalker        77 Human        82.8
# 2 C-3PO                 75 Droid        69.8
# 3 R2-D2                 32 Droid        69.8
# 4 Darth Vader          136 Human        82.8
# 5 Leia Organa           49 Human        82.8
# 6 Owen Lars            120 Human        82.8
# 7 Beru Whitesun lars    75 Human        82.8
# 8 R5-D4                 32 Droid        69.8
# 9 Biggs Darklighter     84 Human        82.8
#10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        77 Human        82.8
# … with 77 more rows
```

If we want to use the chain, use `GRP` to specify the `g` or grouping variable on the data (`.`)

```
library(dplyr)
starwars %>%
 fselect(name, mass, species) %>%
 fgroup_by(species) %>%
 ftransform(mass_norm = fmean(mass, GRP(.), TRA = 'replace'))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for useful answer. Would appreciate if explain what is wrong in my code.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Does the update helps you.  The functions have `g` or grouping which needs to be specified

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your help. I got it.

Answer (score 2):

`fmutate` worked for me.

```r
library(pacman)
#> Warning: package 'pacman' was built under R version 4.2.1
p_load(dplyr, collapse)
starwars %>%
  fselect(name, mass, species) %>%
  fgroup_by(species) %>%
  fmutate(mass_norm = fmean(mass))
#> # A tibble: 87 × 4
#>    name                mass species mass_norm
#>    <chr>              <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1 Luke Skywalker        77 Human        82.8
#>  2 C-3PO                 75 Droid        69.8
#>  3 R2-D2                 32 Droid        69.8
#>  4 Darth Vader          136 Human        82.8
#>  5 Leia Organa           49 Human        82.8
#>  6 Owen Lars            120 Human        82.8
#>  7 Beru Whitesun lars    75 Human        82.8
#>  8 R5-D4                 32 Droid        69.8
#>  9 Biggs Darklighter     84 Human        82.8
#> 10 Obi-Wan Kenobi        77 Human        82.8
#> # … with 77 more rows
#> 
#> Grouped by:  species  [38 | 2 (5.5) 1-35]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>