# How to use R's {collapse} package to achieve a correct fgroup_by() |> ftransform() output?

Tags: r, dplyr

[`{collapse}`](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/index.html) is an `R` package that allows speedier processing times for both data manipulation and descriptive statistics. Some functionality [intentionally echoes `{dplyr}`](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/articles/collapse_and_dplyr.html). For example, compare the following `dplyr` code versus `collapse` code. They are very similar in syntax and yield the same output.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(collapse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> collapse 1.6.5, see ?`collapse-package` or ?`collapse-documentation`
#> Note: stats::D  ->  D.expression, D.call, D.name

using_dplyr <- 
  mpg |>
  group_by(manufacturer) |>
  summarise(mean_hwy = mean(hwy))

using_collapse <- 
  mpg |>
  collapse::fgroup_by(manufacturer) |>
  collapse::fsummarise(mean_hwy = mean(hwy))

identical(using_collapse, using_dplyr)
#> [1] TRUE
```

But `{collapse}` is just faster

```r
bench::mark(dplyr = 
              mpg |>
              group_by(manufacturer) |>
              summarise(mean_hwy = mean(hwy)),
            
            collapse = 
              mpg |>
              fgroup_by(manufacturer) |>
              fsummarise(mean_hwy = mean(hwy))) |>
  autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

**My question:**

Whereas the following expressions are analogous and working:

`group_by() |> summarise()` = `fgroup_by() |> fsummrise()`,

the following analogy doesn't work:

`group_by() |> mutate() |>` != `fgroup_by() |> ftransform()`. (`ftransform()` is `collapse`'s equivalent to `dplyr::mutate()`).

*Demonstrating the problem*

Let's show the same pipe in two equivalent syntaxes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(collapse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> collapse 1.6.5, see ?`collapse-package` or ?`collapse-documentation`
#> Note: stats::D  ->  D.expression, D.call, D.name

is_bigger_than_mean <- function(x) {
  x > mean(x)
}

## dplyr syntax
mutate_using_dplyr <- 
  mpg |>
  select(manufacturer, hwy) |>
  group_by(manufacturer) |>
  mutate(hwy_bigger_than_mean = is_bigger_than_mean(hwy))

## collapse syntax
mutate_using_collapse <- 
  mpg |>
  fselect(manufacturer, hwy) |>
  fgroup_by(manufacturer) |>
  ftransform(hwy_bigger_than_mean = is_bigger_than_mean(hwy))
```

Compare the results in the column `hwy_bigger_than_mean`

```r
mutate_using_dplyr  ## correct
#> # A tibble: 234 x 3
#> # Groups:   manufacturer [15]
#>    manufacturer   hwy hwy_bigger_than_mean
#>    <chr>        <int> <lgl>               
#>  1 audi            29 TRUE                
#>  2 audi            29 TRUE                
#>  3 audi            31 TRUE                
#>  4 audi            30 TRUE                
#>  5 audi            26 FALSE               
#>  6 audi            26 FALSE               
#>  7 audi            27 TRUE                
#>  8 audi            26 FALSE               
#>  9 audi            25 FALSE               
#> 10 audi            28 TRUE                
#> # ... with 224 more rows

mutate_using_collapse ## incorrect
#> # A tibble: 234 x 3
#>    manufacturer   hwy hwy_bigger_than_mean
#>  * <chr>        <int> <lgl>               
#>  1 audi            29 TRUE                
#>  2 audi            29 TRUE                
#>  3 audi            31 TRUE                
#>  4 audi            30 TRUE                
#>  5 audi            26 TRUE                
#>  6 audi            26 TRUE                
#>  7 audi            27 TRUE                
#>  8 audi            26 TRUE                
#>  9 audi            25 TRUE                
#> 10 audi            28 TRUE                
#> # ... with 224 more rows
#> 
#> Grouped by:  manufacturer  [15 | 16 (11)]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

What causes the difference? And is it possible to achieve a correct output such that `mutate_using_collapse` will give the same output as `mutate_using_dplyr`?

***note:*** a similar question discusses a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67349744/using-ftransform-along-with-fgroup-by-from-collapse-r-package)

Comment: Per the documentation: “Please note that unlike dplyr::mutate, ftransform does not do anything per se with a grouped data frame.” — My guess is that the package buys the increased performance by removing functionality.

Comment: Just reading this issue. I think a mistake I made is to mention `dplyr::mutate` in the documentation. `ftransform` is a faster and more versatile replacement for `base::transform`, as the name suggests. From an engineering point of view, it is difficult to optimize the functionality of `mutate` by groups because expressions could be arbitrary e.g. `mutate(newcol = col1 - FUN(col2) + FUN2(col3)) requires `FUN1` and `FUN2` to be executed for each group. In general, {collapse} does not execute any R functions by groups, all grouped operations are implemented in C++ by fast statistical functions.

Comment: In terms of a general 'split-apply-combine' computing mechanism, I recommend `data.table` which has a very fast mechanism to execute arbitrary expressions by groups. Note that also `data.table` only reaches very high speeds for functions it internally optimizes, see `?GForce`, and most of these optimizations are also only available for aggregation. The mission of {collapse} is to provide similarlar optimized functions and some supporting grammar that can be applied to vectors matrices and misc. tabular data, supports weighted computations, and data transformations required in econometrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Konrad has pointed out, `ftransform()` is not a 1-to-1 stand-in for `mutate()` as it's, by design, more limited in scope, doesn't respect grouped data by default, and is mainly intended to be used with a restricted set of "fast" functions in the package.

You can use the `fmean()` function to achieve your goal but need to explicitly tell it to use the grouped data using the `GRP()` function.

Note also that it won't work with the new base R pipes, you need to use magrittr pipes for the grouping data to be available to the function call.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)

mpg %>%
   fselect(manufacturer, hwy) %>%
   fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>%
   ftransform(hwy_bigger_than_mean = hwy > fmean(hwy, GRP(.), TRA = "replace")) 

# A tibble: 234 x 3
   manufacturer   hwy hwy_bigger_than_mean
 * <chr>        <int> <lgl>               
 1 audi            29 TRUE                
 2 audi            29 TRUE                
 3 audi            31 TRUE                
 4 audi            30 TRUE                
 5 audi            26 FALSE               
 6 audi            26 FALSE               
 7 audi            27 TRUE                
 8 audi            26 FALSE               
 9 audi            25 FALSE               
10 audi            28 TRUE                
# ... with 224 more rows
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. So basically I cannot use any non-`collapse` function within `ftransform()`, right? Because only `collapse` functions have the built-in grouping argument.

Comment: My understanding is that collapse is intended as an adjunct to dplyr, not a replacement.  In those cases where collapse can speed up calculations it provides something and otherwise expects you to use dplyr.  Note that in this case this also works where `B` (stands for between) is like `ave` in R. 
 `slt` is a short form for `fselect` and `tfm` is a short form for `ftransform`. `mpg |>
  slt(hwy, manufacturer) |>
  tfm(hwy_bigger_than_mean = hwy > B(hwy, manufacturer))`

Comment: and this also works:  `mpg %>% slt(hwy, manufacturer) |> fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>% tfm(bigger = hwy > B(hwy, GRP(.)))`

Comment: I still face some inconsistencies. Consider the utility function `name_with_letter <- function(x) { v <- setNames(x, sample(letters, 1) ); collapse::qDF(v, "name_letter") }`. Then run the pipe: `mpg %>% fselect(manufacturer, hwy) %>% fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>% ftransform(new_col = map(.x = hwy, .f = ~name_with_letter(.x) )) %>% fungroup() %>% tidyr::unnest(new_col)`. Works!

Comment: So I'm unsure how I can know when `ftransform()` is expected to work and when it isn't. when it comes to non-native `collapse` functions.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I'll be grateful if you could chime in too :)

Comment: @Emman, In your `name_with_letter` example, if remove the `fgroup_by`  line you get the same result.  `set.seed(123);
out1 <- mpg %>% 
  fselect(manufacturer, hwy) %>% 
  fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  ftransform(new_col = map(.x = hwy, .f = ~name_with_letter(.x) )) %>% 
  fungroup() %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(new_col);

set.seed(123);
out2 <- mpg %>% 
  fselect(manufacturer, hwy) %>% 
  ftransform(new_col = map(.x = hwy, .f = ~name_with_letter(.x) )) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(new_col);
identical(out1, out2)` gives TRUE.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, you're right. Bad example.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.7.0 of collapse there is now a 'fmutate' function that does computations on grouped data.

```
mpg %>%
   fselect(manufacturer, hwy) %>%
   fgroup_by(manufacturer) %>%
   fmutate(hwy_bigger_than_mean = hwy > fmean(hwy))
```